# Why "science fiction" and not "scientific fiction"?

Tags: etymology, meaning-in-context

Everybody knows the term "science fiction" 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_fiction

But I am wondering why "science fiction" and not grammatically more correct form "scientific fiction"?

Consider similar case:

"nucleus reaction" vs "nuclear reaction"

I am sure that "nuclear reaction" is the correct one.

So, why "science fiction" is more used than "scientific fiction" if "scientific fiction" is the more correct form when considering grammar?

Comment: Because it is not fiction constructed according to scientific principles but fiction about plausible extensions of modern science.

Comment: Why is it "mystery novels" and not "mysterious novels"? Why is it "science reporting", "sports reporting" and "business reporting", and not "scientific reporting", "sportive reporting", and "commercial reporting"?

Comment: @PeterShor I am asking that because in Czech there is for SF used the term "vědecká fikce" = "scientific fiction". And all your other examples are in Czech formed similarly by "adjective + noun" as well. E.g. "sports reporting" = "sportová reportáž". It may seem to you weird. But for me it seems "science fiction" too. However, I must admit that science fiction sounds cooler than scientific fiction ;) EN is very old language, that is basically the same for 500 years or more. It's very proto-language like language when compared with Czech (we have genders, cases and other additional features).

Comment: In Portuguese we also use the correspondent to 'scientific fiction', and lots of students will try to translate it literally. I tell them that it is science fiction because it is a type of fiction, mush like birthday party and wedding party are types of parties, and therefore it doesn't really have to be an adjective. I'm not exactly sure if my explanation is grammatically sound, but I do try to limit technical grammar to the minimum so as not to create resistance from students who are 'allergic' to grammar.

Comment: Why must you always compare English to Czech, as if one language is more logical than the other? They are two separate languages which have evolved independently from each other. I could easily ask why are detective books not called "Yellow"? Seems absurd? Outlandish? Yet in Italian that is exactly how they're called. Why not *fantasy science* instead of *science fiction*? The stories are not necessarily based on real science, they are created by the fantasy of the author. Hence in Italian they are called *fantascienza*.

Comment: Once upon a time, the genre was referred to as [scientifiction](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scientifiction). I was somewhat surprised to find the term listed in a dictionary.

Comment: @Gnawme: There was a contest between the advocates of "scientifiction" and "science fiction".  Of course we know which was the winner.

Comment: because science is not always scientific

Comment: According to the OED, "science-fiction" was also in vogue for a while.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has suggested a comparison with "historical fiction".  If it's "science fiction", why not "history fiction"?  If it's "historical fiction", why not "scientific fiction"?

Comment: This may not be relevant to the actual question, but ... (Derfer) You've made some fairly strange statements in your comment to PeterShor.   Claims that English is "very old" and "same for 500 years or more" are both dubious at best.   More jarringly, either I misunderstand what you're trying to say about 'proto-language', or you're way off base.

Comment: @hunter2 Why proto-language: 1)Gender is at best only weakly grammaticalized in Modern EN (friend is he or she? ;)) 2)No declension (It's very funny to hear an Englishman trying to speak Czech,he sounds like a robot/caveman, because he uses only Nominative ;).) 3)phonetic representation is very archaic and ambiguous (to/too/two)  4)its tenses and grammar is very old and illogical when comapred with younger Slavic langauges like modern Czech or Slovak or constructed languages like Esperanto and .lojban. ;) Sorry, if I offended you, but it's true. Although, I still like how EN sounds in songs ;)

Comment: @Derfder: Languages always evolves as long as there is new material written in it. There are two directions languages can evolve: becoming simpler or becoming more complex. However, more often both are happening at the same time with certain parts of the language getting simpler while other parts getting more complex, and this evolution can go to different directions in different regions where the language is spoken. There is no objective measure of primitive vs modern language.

Comment: @Derfder: The same thing happens with biological evolution. Unlike is popularly misunderstood, humans are not descended from gorillas; instead humans and gorillas are (distant) cousins. Also commonly misunderstood, gorillas/ape/chimp are not proto-humans, and neither is the vice versa; there are parts (e.g. brain, motor skills in hands) that are more advanced in human while other parts (e.g. strength, motor skill in feets) are more advanced in gorillas. These differences evolves due to different evolutionary pressures. Likewise, languages evolves in different directions due to differing needs.

Comment: I agree. BUt it is a consensus that French is very old and inefficient language. There are jokes that even Neanderthals and Cro-Magnon people were speaking French. E.g. modern Czech is very efficient language especially in science and Chemistry. E.g. we can  use our own very logiacal system based on simple math and logic names for chemical molecules, the famous system developed by Vojtěch Šafařík (-ný, -natý, -itý, -ičitý, ičný (-ečný), -ový, -istý, -ičelý) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_chemical_nomenclature . So, we can use the more logical names instead of the names used by EN speakers.

Comment: No, no problem, you didn't offend me personally.   That said, it is not simply 'true' - or, it is truly not simple.  I'm far from the most qualified to go into detail, but language and its evolution are much more complex than that - @LieRyan says nicely what I mean.   Your 'consensus' on French is, I'm pretty sure, colloquial and jocular, not a 'real' linguistic consensus.   Certainly I agree that English is not always logical, but that's mostly because it's such a 'mutt' / 'melting-pot' of a language - the opposite of being an ancient proto-language.

Comment: Further, contemporary English is pretty young.   Even Old English isn't that old, relatively.   In some ways, Latin is more logical, and it's obviously older.   2) ESL speakers from many Asian languages often sound primitive, too, usually because of differences in particle usage and verb tense - but many of these languages are incredibly complex (ie, tones!), and have vocabulary not found in other languages.  3) The IUPAC specifies a very rigid logical set of rules for chemical names, that professionals use.  Common names are different.   Is it that different in Czech?

Comment: Questions and answers should be based on fact. The question wrongly assumes "'scientific fiction' is the more correct form when considering grammar", making the question moot.

Comment: @hunter2: The article linked by Derfder notes that *"Several changes were applied to the basic terminology during the second half of the twentieth century, usually moving closer to the international nomenclature... Adoption of these changes by the Czech public has been quite slow, and the older terms are still used decades later."* According to http://www.iupac.org/home/about/adhering-organizations/national-adhering-organizations.html , both the Czech Republic and Slovakia have IUPAC national adhering organisations.

Comment: @MarkBannister OK. I don't really see how that quote (or the rest of the linked page) support, or are consistent with, Derfder's statement.  Maybe when he comes back from the time-out corner, he'll clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One early candidate for what we now call SF was "scientifiction," a term coined by Hugo Gernsback, an early SF editor and publisher for whom the Hugo Awards are now named. This term neatly overlaps the final syllable of "scientific" and the first of "fiction." However, although he preferred "scientifiction," Gernsback *also* coined the term "science fiction." The latter is what caught on with the public and was later shortened to "sci-fi."

You'd have to ask him why "science fiction" and not "scientific fiction." Unfortunately, he died in 1967. I assume it was because the doubled "fic" syllable was awkward to pronounce and made the speaker sound like he had a stutter. "Scientifiction" might have been an attempt to ameliorate that issue but it, too, is awkward, in my opinion. "Science fiction" does slide more easily off the tongue.

Answer (score 15):

"Science fiction" is not ungrammatical. The [earliest example](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/172674?redirectedFrom=science+fiction#eid) of its use dates back to 1851, according to the Oxford English Dictionary. Google Ngram Viewer [agrees](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scientific+fiction%2C+science+fiction&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) with the OED, showing that "science fiction" is far more popular than "scientific fiction."

Also consider terms like "science book," "science fair," "science experiment"[1], "science teacher," and "Science Guy." These all objects, events, or positions relating to science but not (necessarily) applying scientific principles or methods.

Finally, as Peter Shor pointed out, many other genre names follow the same convention because the word before "fiction" often describes the content, not the style.

[1]: Of course, "scientific experiment" is also common.

Comment: "Science fiction" is not ungrammatical: care to elaborate?

Comment: @Kris: It is not ungrammatical, as nouns can be used as adjectives, and that is exactly what is happening here.

Comment: Which I see is the soul of the answer and should have been there, rather in an obscure comment, right? :)

Comment: The difference between physics education and physical education is rather dramatic.

Comment: But it is "historical fiction" rather than "history fiction"

Comment: Crazy language. One would probably expect 'historical fiction' to be that written before 1800 say. Historical artifacts are old ones, but historical fiction and records needn't be.

Comment: I would say *nouns can be used attributively*, rather than *nouns can be used as adjectives*.  Compare "This apple is very red" to *"This fiction is very science".

Comment: @snailboat: Close, but no cigar. Compare "The explosion was very nuclear." The 'very' test cannot be used to unequivocally distinguish between nouns and adjectives. Grammarians are still divided on whether the common usage involved is 'noun behaving as if it were an adjective' or 'word usually a noun becoming an adjective in this usage'.

Answer (score 8):

At http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives/noun-modifiers is an article showing the common and grammatical use of noun modifiers (aka adjunct nouns); whether or not they remain nouns in this usage is moot.

I'll just quote (with some tidying):

> We often put two nouns together and readers/listeners have to know or
>   work out what they mean.  So:
>
> an ice bucket = a bucket to keep ice in
>
> an ice cube = a cube made of ice
>
> an ice breaker = a ship which breaks ice
>
> the Ice Age = the time when much of the Earth was covered in ice.

**Not** an icy bucket / an icy cube / an icy breaker / the Icy Age!

Words readily undergo **semantic conversion** (becoming another part of speech as well as the original one - or at least being used as if they did) in English. Perhaps the OP would be disturbed to know that *nuclear* is used as a noun:

> '...fossil fuels are a clear and present threat to the American way of
>   life, and that renewables won't fix it, and that nuclear is the only
>   solution.'

(Google

Answer (score 1):

Science is a much more general word than scientific.  Scientific suggests something more factual and therefore fiction is not used in conjuction with the word scientific.